# CSS3 Arrow animation is not working

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I am trying to animate an arrow downwards to indicate scroll down in a parallex site.
I have got this code from Codepen.
See working demo here : [CodePen arrow animation](http://codepen.io/szs/pen/JhgKC?editors=110)

I am exactly using the same code on my site but it does not animate.
The arrow shows up but it does not animate.
What I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="encircle bounce animated">
 <div class="arrow">
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    @mixin keyframes($name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content; 
  }
  @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  } 
}
@mixin animation($animation) {
  -webkit-animation: #{$animation};
    -moz-animation: #{$animation};
    -ms-animation: #{$animation};
    animation: #{$animation};
}
@mixin transform($transform) {
  -webkit-transform: $transform;
  -moz-transform: $transform;
  -ms-transform: $transform;
  transform: $transform;
}

@include keyframes(bounce) {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    @include transform(translateY(0));
  }
    40% {
    @include transform(translateY(-20px));
  }
    60% {
    @include transform(translateY(-10px));
  }
}


body {
  background: black;
}

.encircle {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius:60px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.arrow {
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
  @include animation(bounce 2s infinite);
}
```

Comment: You know that you're using SCSS (SASS), not CSS3, right?

Comment: @taylorc93 Oh I just found out yeah. I never heard of SASS though before.
Is there any pure CSS3 way to do this animation? Or how do I setup SASS to run on my site? I am looking for something easy that works.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be compile the SCSS you have to regular CSS and try that.  http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass

Comment: @taylorc93 Did you not recognize that none of that code *looked* like CSS (or at least, not any CSS you were familiar with)?  Why didn't you start by searching for what those things mean?  Searching for "css mixin"  or "css keyframe" would have put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **SASS** source code and it'll not work for you if you just include it like a css file. you need a **SASS pre-compiler** or use directly the generated css

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
body {
  background: black;
}

.encircle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.arrow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  -ms-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
```

to read more about [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the CSS. However, I still don't understand how did you get this generated CSS? How do I convert SAAS to CSS?
Did you just copied the code from browser inspect element?

Comment: You can install **SASS** pre-compiler or just inspect the generated **css** on the [codepen snippet](http://codepen.io/szs/pen/JhgKC?editors=110) using the chrome console.